# Windows 10 (Upgrade from windows 7) won't dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7, windows-10

This situation is the PC was upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Then Ubuntu was installed.  When I installed it the prompt asked if I wanted to install it along side Windows 7 even though the upgrade to 10 was complete.

I proceeded with the installation and it appeared to complete without errors.

However, it still boots directly to Windows 10 without a dual boot option.

At this point I am not sure how to boot to Ubuntu to fix grub.  I have read some solutions for grub but I need to get into Ubuntu first.

The option to "try Ubuntu" works but that is only running off the thumb-drive.

Any suggestions?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look on this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: Make sure you have Windows 10 repair flash drive. Your Windows 7 was probably BIOS/MBR, so when Windows breaks, you will not be able to boot Windows from grub menu.And then need to reinstall Windows boot loader temporarily to fix Windows and then reinstall grub's boot loader. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader &https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System Also make sure Windows 10 fast start up or always on hibernation is off. Updates may turn it back on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Answer (score 0):

1. log into windows partition
2. install [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)
3. download [Grub2](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) iso,
4. use UNetbootin, to create a bootable USB with it.

then restart your system, and boot using the bootable USB.

that will allows you to fix your GRUB.